# How to use cron in custom module

Tags: module, event-observer, cron

in `observer.php`

```
public function sendProductAlert()
{
    Mage::log('cron working');

    $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('product_alert_stock'=>'product_alert_stock'));
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
    Mage::log( $allrecord );
    $somevar = 'Hello check';

    Mage::log( $somevar );
    // die('cron');
    return $this;
}
```

`In config.xml`

```
 <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <amasty_amxnotif_alert>
            <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run>
                <model>amxnotif/observer::sendProductAlert</model>
            </run>
        </amasty_amxnotif_alert>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

There are two files at root 
1. `cron.sh` file permission 0744
2. `cron.php` file permission 0744

still my function don't exexuted

`If there is no cron scheduled in cpannel how magento productAlert module sends mail ?`

Comment: did you added cron.sh file in crontab?

Comment: where is this `crontab` in module ?

Comment: are you checking in localhost?

Comment: no on live server

Comment: check this https://blog.amasty.com/configure-magento-cron-job/

Comment: if you want to run cron manually  you can use this extension(For M1) -https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Comment: if i schedule cron.sh from cpannel does it execute all the cron job of all modules ?

Comment: Yes it will run all the cron jobs

Comment: ok , as in my cpannel no cron job is cheduled , so lets create for every 5 minutes as per the above link

Comment: one more question what would be the path if cron.sh is on root directory

Comment: sh cron.sh  or sh /websitename.com/cron.sh/

Comment: it will be path_to_your_magento_root_directory/cron.sh

Comment: ok i cheduled one for every 5 minute .

Comment: is there any error in my above codes

Comment: still i don't get any entry in `SELECT * from cron_schedule where job_code like '%alert%'`